# Summary table using Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I've programmed a summary chart, and I'm trying to add a "Totals" line that will sum up three columns. The exercise is comprised of a number of questions, and the participant can increase, decrease or maintain a certain dollar amount. The column B total shows the initial values (where the slider starts off on). The column C shows the amount the participant either increased or decreased and the last column shows the resulting dollar amount. (B + C)

Here's an example of the summary chart

**Column A --- B ------ C------ D**

Question 1 | 100$ | +28$ | 128$ |
Question 2 | 150$  | (10$) | 140$  |

Totals ------| 250$ | +18$ | 268$ |

So far I've been able to program the totals for column B and D, but I can't figure out how to show a total for column C.

```
class window.CustomSimulator extends window.TaxSimulator
  constructor: (@options = {}) ->
    super
    @updateTable()

update: ->
  super
  @updateTable()

updateTable: ->
  self = this

  $table = $('<table class="table table-condensed"><thead><tr><th>Category</th><th>Before</th><th>Your Choice</th><th>After</th></tr></table>')
  $tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>')

  before_total = 0
  after_total = 0

  @scope.find('.slider').each ->
    $this = $(this)
    $parents = $this.parents('tr')

    category    = $parents.find('.header').clone().children().remove().end().text().replace(/How would you adjust service levels and property tax funding for /, '').replace('?', '')
    before      = self.tipScaler($this, $this.data('initial'))
    your_choice = $parents.find('.value').text()
    after       = $parents.find('.tip-content').text()

  if $parents.find('.key').text() == 'Decrease:'
    css_class = 'decrease'
    your_choice = "(#{your_choice})"
  else
    css_class = 'increase'

  $tr = $("""<tr><td>#{category}</td><td>#{before}</td><td class="table-#{css_class}">#{your_choice}</td><td>#{after}</td></tr>""")
  $tbody.append($tr)

  before_total += parseFloat(before.replace('$', ''))
  after_total += parseFloat(after.replace('$', ''))

  before_total = SimulatorHelper.number_to_currency(before_total, precision: 2, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
  after_total = SimulatorHelper.number_to_currency(after_total, precision: 2, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
  $("""<tfoot><tr><th>Totals</th><th>#{before_total}</th></th><th><th>#{after_total}</th></tr></tfoot>""").appendTo($table)

$table.append($tbody)
$('#summary-table').html($table)
```

I'm pretty new at this so I'm not sure if this is enough information.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer?